# Can we use Rouche's theorem for $z^5 + 3z^4 + 6$ on $|z| = 3$?

Tags: complex-analysis

This is from an exam.

How many zeroes of $f(z) = z^5 + 3z^4 + 6$ are within $|z| = 3$?

The test is for a class based on Complex Variables and their applications, so of course Rouche's theorem is what I went for. However, it seemed very difficult to get this function into a form that we could work with Rouche's theorem.

After thinking about the question afterwards, here's the best I could do to muster up an answer:

Use Rouche's theorem on $|z| = 2$. We get $4$ zeroes within this contour.

Furthermore, $f(z)$ has a real root since it's of odd degree. Hence, this root must be of the form $-r$ with $r > 0$. At $r = 3$, we have $f(-3) = 6$ and the function is decreasing as $r$ increases, hence this zero is larger than three. So there are $\boxed{4}$ zeroes in total.

Is there an easier, more direct way to get this result? I suspect there is since the other version of the exam had $f(z) = z^4 + 3z^3 + 6$ which is also hard to use Rouche's theorem on and cannot be solved in this manner.

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of a better way to answer your main question.  Here is a solution for the implied question at the end.

Let $f(z)=z^4+3z^3+6$.  By Rouche on $|z|=2$ we have exactly three roots inside $|z|=2$.  Since for real $x$ we have $f'(x)=4x^3+9x^2$, we see that there is a minimum at $x=-9/4$.  We now have enough information to draw the graph and conclude that there is a real root between $-3$ and $-9/4$.  This is not one that we counted before, so the answer is: four roots.

IMHO this is reasonably similar in difficulty to your version of the exam.

**Edit** re drawing the graph.  We can tell that $f(-9/4)<0$ by direct calculation, or more neatly as follows.  Since $f$ has real coefficients, complex roots come in conjugate pairs.  So from the first part of the solution we see that there is a real root with $-2<x<2$.  This forces $f(-9/4)<0$.

Comment: Gotcha. It was just unsettling to see this much work needed since our exams and exercises in the past have been all very basic applications of the theorems we learned. Wasn't expecting to actually have to think in this class, I guess :p